# How can I troubleshoot a custom HTML, CSS, and JavaScript carousel not working on Gohighlevel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I can't get custom coded (HTML, CSS, & Javascript) Carousel / Slider to work on my webpage (relationshipdynamics (dot) com). I'm using the Go High level drag and drop web builder to create the page with their custom code element which allows for Javascript, HTML, and CSS. I have other custom code elements working on the page. I'm stumped and so is Chat Gpt4.  I know CSS and some HTML but I don't really know any Javascript so keep that in mind.  Grateful for any help.

**ISSUES**

1. About 20px of the next Slide (2) is displaying on the far right div (Next Icon). I used box-sizing, overflow hidden, am using flex etc so can't figure out what's not working.
2. The dots, previous & next icons aren't clickable and the slider isn't scrolling to the next slide after 6000 milliseconds so nothing seems to be animating.

**HTML CSS & Javascript code**

```
[Message was too long had to omit html]

<style>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 30px; /* Added padding to move chevrons outside */
}

.slides-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.slide {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.column {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Added to ensure padding doesn't affect overall width */
}

.column.narrower {
  width: 25%; /* Adjusted width */
}

.column.wider {
  width: 75%; /* Adjusted width */
}

.testimonial-image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover; /* Ensures the image fits nicely in the circle */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Centers the image */
  display: block;
}

.subtitle {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.testimonial-text {
  font-family: "Open Sans Light", sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.chevron {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 100;
}

.chevron.prev {
  background-image: url("https://storage.googleapis.com/msgsndr/fi0Di40dhB0LWBT2pwFn/media/6477b5c3ac275ec5d5fe0917.png");
  left: 0; /* Set to edge of the container */
  top: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.chevron.next {
  background-image: url("https://storage.googleapis.com/msgsndr/fi0Di40dhB0LWBT2pwFn/media/6477b5c3d15d671863cbf653.png");
  right: 0; /* Set to edge of the container */
  top: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.dots-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px; /* Adjust to desired position */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dot.active {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Change the testimonial to 2 columns */
    .testimonial {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
    
    /* Reduce text size to 14px */
    .testimonial-subtitle,
    .testimonial-text {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
</style>

<script>
// JavaScript code to handle the carousel functionality
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const slidesContainer = document.querySelector(".slides-container");
  const prevButton = document.querySelector(".chevron.prev");
  const nextButton = document.querySelector(".chevron.next");
  const dots = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dot"));

  console.log({slidesContainer, prevButton, nextButton, dots});

  let currentSlide = 0;
  let intervalId;

  function goToSlide(index) {
    slidesContainer.style.transform = `translateX(-${index * 100}%)`;
    currentSlide = index;

    // Update active dot
    dots.forEach((dot, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        dot.classList.add("active");
      } else {
        dot.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });
  }

  function startCarousel() {
    intervalId = setInterval(goToNextSlide, 6000);
  }

  function stopCarousel() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }

  function goToNextSlide() {
    currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % dots.length;
    goToSlide(currentSlide);
  }

  function goToPrevSlide() {
    currentSlide = (currentSlide - 1 + dots.length) % dots.length;
    goToSlide(currentSlide);
  }

  // Event listeners
  prevButton.addEventListener("click", goToPrevSlide);
  nextButton.addEventListener("click", goToNextSlide);
  dots.forEach((dot, i) => dot.addEventListener("click", () => goToSlide(i)));

  // Start the carousel
  startCarousel();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Here is the website: https://relationshipdynamics.com

Html (was too long to post but I could post it in parts if needed)